# Autocomplete field in odoo 8

Tags: python, autocomplete, odoo, odoo-8

I'm trying to add autocomplete to the 'Internal reference' field (default_code) in Product page. More exactly, I would like that when I start typing a new 'reference' to have a list displayed with previously entered 'references' that match what I have typed so far. Something like the Customers -> Create -> Company name field.

I'm a beginner with odoo and I can't seem to find a way to do this. I assume it has to do something with defining a proper on_change, but I can't figure it out. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

i will give you an example of on_change function:-

```
.py code
def onchange_dept_id(self, cr, uid, ids, department_id, context=None):
    res = {}
    if department_id:
        code = self.pool.get('department.department').browse(cr, uid, department_id, context=context).code
        if not code:
            res.update({'dept_code':''})
            warning = {'title': _('Warning !'),'message': _('Code is not defined in the selected department!')}
            return {'warning': warning, 'value':res}
        res.update({'dept_code' : code})
    return {'value' : res}
```

xml code:-

```
<field name="department_id" on_change="onchange_dept_id(department_id)" attrs="{'readonly':[('state','!=','draft')]}"/>
```

if you want check it, more details [enter link description here](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-use-on-change-function-23694)